# Setting Permissions with SyncPermissionValue not working with Synchronized Realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I created a Realm with an Admin account and I want all other users to be able to read/write from this shared realm. According to the docs, this should do the trick as I'm using the `*` for the userId. However, this isn't working as I am unable to pull any of the user object in this realm from the Realm Object Server if I am logged in to a non-admin account. Additionally, when I log into the Realm Object Server with my admin account, the default permissions say "no access" for every realm. The console is printing this while I'm trying to apply the permissions on my admin account:

> Error Domain=io.realm.sync.permission Code=1 "The path is invalid or current user has no access." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The path is invalid or current user has no access., statusCode=614}

I know the path is correct because I'm able to create a realm instance using a `SyncConfiguration` with that path.

Versioning:
RealmSwift 2.8.3, iOS 10.3.2, Xcode 8.3.3, ROS 1.7.6

```
let permission = SyncPermissionValue(realmPath: RealmURL.userObjects.absoluteString, userID: "*", accessLevel: .write) // may write
SyncUser.current!.applyPermission(permission) { (error) in
if let error = error {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: @bdash thanks for the edits.

Comment: Could you try logging whatever `RealmURL.userObjects.absoluteString` is, as well as whether `SyncUser.current!.isAdmin` is true or false, and sharing the results in a comment?

Comment: Admin is true, URL is http://***:port/userObjects

Comment: Can you just pass in the `/userObjects` portion for that argument? (We really need to clarify our documentation for that method...)

Comment: @AustinZ okay so just to confirm - for the realmPath only put "/userObjects"?

Comment: Yes, pass in only "/userObjects".

Comment: @AustinZ Sorry for the duplicate with Github. I wasn't originally sure if this was the exact cause for my SyncUserSession lasting indefinitely.

Comment: No worries, I'm glad you got it worked out in the end.